# PHP - Validate phone number

Tags: php, regex

I need to validate phone number in PHP, but the example below do not work.

```
$phone = '(123) 458-1542';

if(preg_match("/^([0-9]{3})-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/", $phone)) {

}
```

Comment: there is `()` in `$phone`

Comment: Is the number in your example supposed to be valid or invalid? *How should we know?* If you need to *build* / *check* / *validate* regex, **use a tool** for that, for example: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a space and escape the round brackets:

```
^\([0-9]{3}\)[- ][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
 ^^        ^^^^^^
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE5gU0/1)

I added a [**character class**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) `[- ]` just in case there can be *either* a space *or* a hyphen after the area code. Parentheses must be escaped in order to be treated as literal symbols and not as a [**grouping construct**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php).

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/h8M8kC):

```
$phone = '(123) 458-1542';
if(preg_match('~^\([0-9]{3}\)[- ][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$~', $phone)) {
    echo "Matched: $phone";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this regex:

```
^\(*\+*[1-9]{0,3}\)*-*[1-9]{0,3}[-. /]*\(*[2-9]\d{2}\)*[-. /]*\d{3}[-. /]*\d{4} *e*x*t*\.* *\d{0,4}$
```

Following phone numbers have been tested:

```
1-234-567-8901
1-234-567-8901 x1234
1-234-567-8901 ext1234
1 (234) 567-8901
1.234.567.8901
1/234/567/8901
12345678901
1-234-567-8901 ext. 1234
(+351) 282 433 5050
```

Example: http://www.regexr.com/3bp4b

Comment: Best answer so far. The others are too strict with spaces/hyphens/brackets etc